# Downloading packages from ubuntu repositories (apt) manually using wget

Tags: apt, repository, add-apt-repository

I want to learn about how apt works & fetches objects from mirrors in `sources.list`. How can I browse these repositories manually, download them manually & build them manually (not using source and not github, etc...)?

Comment: You can browse using any web browser. A proper apt source is an ordinary URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I want to download a specific version of a package manually with `wget`, I use [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/). This site basically have an index of all major repositories, and provide many package details.

It supports a solid handful of distros beside Ubuntu (you can find newer packages by installing from Debian unstable for instance), and both `amd64` and `arm64` architectures.

Here you can browse or search for any package, and you'll get the download link directly.

Take this example with [Nano for Ubuntu 20.04](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/nano_4.8-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb.html).

You get a download link, a list of dependencies, list of files etc. To download this package manually, you just fire `wget` with the link provided:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nano/nano_4.8-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

You can then proceed to do whatever you want with the package.

Comment: More trust is here - https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/nano .

Comment: The download link is ultimately the same - but yes, it's of course a good idea to validate the link in more than one place.

Comment: [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/) looks great. is there a cli tool that can somewhat function like apt but rather fetches the packages from pkgs.org?

Answer (score 0):

Manual package download will end with dependency hell on some another try.

This is why I have I have created special Docker-based script for my personal needs. It is located at https://github.com/N0rbert/deb-download .
Currently this script supports every Debian and Ubuntu versions which have docker base images on dockerhub, thus Ubuntu from 12.04 LTS, Debian from 6 and Mint from 18. Both EOL and actual releases are supported by script.

How to use:

1. Know the needed Debian *derivative* name (like Debian itself, Ubuntu and Mint), its *codename* and the *package* name by using local tools like `apt-cache policy`, `rmadison`; or by visiting https://packages.debian.org , https://packages.ubuntu.com , http://packages.linuxmint.com , https://repology.org , https://pkgs.org , etc .
2. Install Docker on the machine for example using docker.io package (package from docker.com will also work)

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install docker.io git
   sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
   ```

   and reboot machine.
3. Clone the repository and run the script to get package(s) with its(their) dependencies

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   git clone https://github.com/N0rbert/deb-download.git
   cd deb-download
   chmod +x deb-download.sh

   #             derivative codename package(s)
   #                    ↓     ↓        ↓
   ./deb-download.sh ubuntu bionic zenmap
   ```
4. Grab the downloaded deb-packages from `storage` sub-folder. Optionally grab the URL list file from `storage/urls.txt`.
5. Carefully inspect the contents of `storage` subfolder, then try to install main deb-package to the target system, then fix its dependencies one-by-one.

   For example installation of ZenMap on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system is possible by using below commands:

   ```
   cd storage
   sudo apt-get install ./zenmap_7.60-1ubuntu5_all.deb ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
   ```

More details are presented in [README.md](https://github.com/N0rbert/deb-download/blob/master/README.md) and in [deb-download.sh](https://github.com/N0rbert/deb-download/blob/master/deb-download.sh) script itself.