# Are old package versions removed from their Ubuntu apt package repositories just because they're old?

Tags: apt, package-management, canonical

Note: this question can apply to any version. I just chose an end-of-life (and therefore in the past) one in the example to avoid "one can't predict the future"-type answers.

The example, to make the question clearer: if I had kept running `sudo apt-get install <specific-package>=<specific-version> && sudo apt-get remove <specific-package>` on my Ubuntu  once a day for the last 5 years, would I have ever encountered an error due to the package no longer being hosted by Canonical?

Assume problems such as security vulnerabilities or system instability were never found in that package/version.

Comment: Context: I'm writing an Ubuntu-based Dockerfile that `apt-get install`s fixed package versions and am wondering if it would ever break due to the above-mentioned error.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/#:~:text=Old%20releases%20can%20be%20found%20at%20http%3A//old%2Dreleases.ubuntu.com/
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/warty/

Comment: Yes, old packages are removed from repos.

Comment: The most *up-to-date* (*with patches applied*) version is present

Comment: @guiverc 16.04 was just an example. The question is general and can be applied to any version. I'll edit to make this clear.

Comment: @Pilot6 Would you mind expanding on what makes you confident in that assertion? If you can do that in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Probably add an old repo

Comment: Your question as written is off-topic by site rules; so my comment was made along with my close vote. Mine is not the only close-vote so far, so if you want to have your question remain; you should write it in a form that is on-topic for this site (ie. avoiding the EOL/ESM details which is all you discuss). See on-topic link already provided.

Comment: Requiring specific package versions is a recipe for failure.  Why do you think you need to do that?  This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: *"due to the above mentioned error"* - what error?  You have not posted any error.  Why are you linking repos for Warty from 2004?

Comment: @guiverc I've rewritten it, hopefully it is adequate now. I hope the mere appearance of the string "16.04" doesn't get posts closed here, and some nuance is used.

Comment: @Nmath image consistent docker image builds is important for my wider use-case. Having specific package versions is essential for build consistency.

Comment: @Nmath the error is mentioned in the question. A search-in-page for "error" can get you there.

Comment: If 16.04 was used as additional to something that was on-topic it wouldn't be a problem; but your question is purely written about an off-topic EOL/ESM release that is specifically mentioned in site rules as off-topic. ie. "*Support for versions for Ubuntu releases past their "End of Standard Support" or "End of Life" dates (whichever is earlier)*" is listed as off-topic/avoid.  Did you read site rules. Also you mention only Canonical;  note Core-Devs do **not** need to be Canonical employees.. It's Ubuntu, not Canonical's repositories

Comment: @guiverc did you take into consideration the latest edit I made to the question's body? Also, good point about my usage of "Canonical", I've adjusted the title.

Comment: packages can be removed; I've seen many ML posts warning of the upcoming removal - so my prior comment comment about most *up-to-date* maybe inaccurate; esp. for *development* releases (where most changes occur)... I cannot recall a removal included with SRU (ie. for *stable* release though; but capacity for that may exist; sorry I don't know).

Comment: @habit Please remove 16.04 to calm this down. It is a good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All latest packages for all releases are still available at the relevant URLs.

As an example we can select Midnight Commander:

- publishing history maybe obtained at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mc
- its actual versions are found via search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=mc), the files are available at [http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mc/](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mc/?C=M;O=A) since 2013. You should not download them manually because of dependency hell, but they are located here.
- its obsolete versions are still located at [https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mc/](https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mc/?C=M;O=A) since 2004. You should not download them manually because of dependency hell, but they are located here.

If you have specific needs to get old (or exactly specified) package version with its URL - you can use my special Docker [based script](https://github.com/N0rbert/deb-download). More details may be found at [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/1349521/66509).